# Can I record with a keyboard on my PS3?

Tags: ps3, keyboard, recording

Can I record on my PS3 super slim? If so, can I do it with a keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The PS3 may support keyboards, but it does not offer any kind of recording feature. This means you'll have to rely on external devices doing the recording instead of your console.

You'll need a PC equipped with a so-called [**video capture card**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_tuner_card#Video_capture) to do it. You will also need to plug your PS3 to the capture card, and your PC to your TV or whatever screen you wish to play on.

Whether or not you can use a keyboard to control the recording software your capture card will need, that will depend on the software itself. Chances are the software will support keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: is there an alternative in stead of the capture card

Comment: The only alternative I can think of are [**DVR**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video_recorder). Unless you already own one (or your TV has DVR capabilities, which I doubt), a DVR is likely going to cost more than a capture card. The PS4 would be a last resort, but it doesn't play PS3 games. Not without **PS Now**, that is.

Comment: @WesleyTerrellJudkinsJr. Now that I think of it: you *could* set up a camera to record what's happening on your screen. Of course, this means the video and audio quality will be very bad, and playing the game will be very uncomfortable, since you need to be careful not to make too much noise or appear in front of the camera.